# Python pynput to C#

Tags: python, c#, keyboard

I want something similar to code written in Python in Csharp. Is there a module similar to pynput?
Here is an example code that I would like to port.

```
from pynput import keyboard

done = True

def on_release(key):
    if key == keyboard.Key.pause:
        global done
        done = False

listener = keyboard.Listener(on_release=on_release)
listener.start()

while done:
    pass

print("PAUSE")
```